# SQL Statement Error in Syntax When Creating Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQL, and I encountered an error when I tried to make a primary key to be Generated.

I set customer_id attribute to be Primary Key, Not Null, Unique, and Generated so the system will auto generate the value for me.

However, I encountered this error when I clicked on Generate selection.

May I know how can I execute my sql statement to allow system to auto generate the primary key of customer_id?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is that gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the GUI is.  But you want the column to be auto-incremented rather than generated (unless you are using MySQL 8+).

The resulting code could look like:

```
id int auto_increment primary key
```

A primary key is automatically `NULL` and `UNIQUE`, so there is no need to declare those as well.

Comment: The `auto_increment` wasn't clickable for me. In the end I create the table with query instead of using the GUI. But yes, auto_increment is the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto increment(AI)` instead of `auto generate` because `auto generate` is not possible for a PK.